# July 2023 photo competition, theme of 'pets traveling'

Tags: discussion, fun, photo-competition

The theme is 'Pets traveling'.
I see pets quite wide in this, like in all animals that are likely to be traveling other than to be expected. Like a dog in a bag, backpack or a traveling cage. Chickens in a bus. A rat in the sleeve of its owner.

And if you do think this is not a suitable topic, or if you want a different one next month, please post that here as a comment as well.

The usual rules apply, up to three photos of one animal or situation per post.

Feel free to copy the rules in from a previous month.
Or come to the [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) to discuss this.

Comment: @gmauch, it does not have to be your pet. It can be any animal that is transported in such a way that you think 'pet'. Like a horse in a horse box, or on a cart rather than in front of it, a dog that sticks its head out of a car window, a dog in a basket on a bike, even a joey in the pouch of a kangaroo.... if you happen to have that kind of wildlife photos.

Comment: @Willeke Nice! it looks like more fun the way you described it now! English is not my first language, but the word _pet_ reminds me of a domesticated animal kept for companionship or amusement not wildlife animals, am I right? Perhaps the title could be changed to _animals traveling_?

Comment: No, animals traveling would be birds flying or dogs running. I want animals that are transported in such a way you see fun or strange in it. It can be domestic animals, tamed wild animals or wild animals that make use of other animals to move around.

Comment: @Willeke is this now the July 2023 Photo Competition? Previous rules don't ask for camera shot data, as supplied by answers so far. Is this to verify that the shot really was taken by the poster, and not grabbed from the internet (where the EXIF camera data is often missing)? Are photos supposed to be unedited too? Editing can remove EXIF data; I often crop mine for better presentation.

Comment: @WeatherVane, camera details are not needed at all but some people like to add them and they are free to do so. I also mostly crop or reduce size of my photos to make uploading to the site easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit**: the usual rules say "you posted it, stand by it" and also "up to 3 photos per answer". But I wish I had posted a better crop of the image, so I added it.

**"The Lookout"**

[image]

Taken by me on the River Ore near Orford, Suffolk UK in August 2018.

[image]

Comment: Highest voted post, you win the bragging rights this month.

Comment: @Willeke thank you. Will there be an August 2023 competition?

Answer (score 7):

```
NIKON CORPORATION NIKON D80
ƒ/5.61/12524 mmISO160
16 Aug 2011
Ulan Bator, Mongolia
```

Mongolian Eagle in Passenger Seat.

[image]

Comment: Hey, for a moment there I thought this was a self portrait, and not an eagle. :D

Comment: @JoErNanO hadn't noticed but if you zoom and look, you can just see me taking the photo in the reflection! Haha

Comment: You win the virtual prize, most unexpected animal.

Answer (score 5):

```
SONY DSC-V3
ƒ/2.81/307 mmISO250

23 Nov 2007
```

Cat on Motorcycle, Marrakech, Morocco

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On a TGV from Valence TGV > Barcelona Sants, a hard-shell transparent-cover small backpack. Inside, there's an iguana.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My two dogs, Mocha and Luna, travelling in the back of a Toyota.  (Can't see the straps but they are clipped in).

Circa late 2021 at a guess.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is that an adorable baby child in the stroller?  No, it's a hideous hairless cat! Photo taken in Hawaii during September of 2020.

[image: Hawaiian Cat Stroller]